# Como configurar o alinhamento da arvore de arquivos do explorador do vs code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

todos bem ?

Eu sei que possa ser besteira, mas teria alguma forma destes arquivos ficarem alinhados com essa linha ?
Tipo um margin left -5px

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Muito Obrigado Srs

Answer (score 1):

Nos Setting procure por `tree indent`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]